# Django , ajax for button onclick

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have this code in flask, It sends 2 lists to html, one is just number like [1,2,3] and the other some names like [file1,file2,...]

This is the html that makes a table, a column for the first list and the other for the second one and a corresponding button that onclick will send a function to flask that deletes the corresponding file:

```
<div class="row">
        <div>
            <table id="mytables" class="table table-striped" style="float: inherit;">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>file_size</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for id in ids %}
                <tr href="#">
                    <td>{{id+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{file_name[id]}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button onclick="delete_f('{{file_name[id]}}')" id="d{{id}}" type="button"
                                class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Delete
                        </button>


                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the javascript:

```
<script>
        function delete_f(name) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/delete_f',
                data: name,
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    document.location.reload(true);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

 and this is the flask:
@app.route('/delete_f', methods=['POST'])
def delete_f():
    name = request.data
    os.remove('E:/Office/DLP/sourceCode/Flask/newwork/static/files/' + name)
    return "das"
```

this works fine, I want to make it in django, my first problem is that django doesn't support this line : {{file_name[id]}} 
The second problem is that whatever I do, django won't accept the ajax function's POST variables, this is the django code in views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def DeleteJobFile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        name = request.POST('FileName')
        print(name)
        fs.remove('E:/Office/DLP/sourceCode/Flask/newwork/static/files/' + name)
    else:
        print('no')
    return render(request, 'JobApp/JobApp.html', {'FileList': FileList})
```

Comment: 1. try `{{ file_name.id }}`
2. try `name = request.POST["FileName"]`

what kind of error do you get?

Comment: {{file_name.id}} return nothing, as if it doesn't accept id as a number. name = request.POST["FileName"] returns: django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'Filename'

Comment: I'm really stuck, I tried everything but the view function doesn't receive FileName. I tried this : name = request.POST.get('FileName',False), it always returns False. The html is also data:{ 'FileName': name}

Comment: Print the `Post` data. like `print request.POST` and check what kind of data you recive. There should be something. For your template tag problem, when inside a for loop, you would have to use {{ id.id }} to get the ID in your case since you used the "id" as a keyword in the forloop. better would be `{% for object in ids %} {{ object.id }}`....

Comment: Print(request.post) gave <QueryDict: {}>

Comment: try `print request` and  `print request.body`, are you sending a CSRF token along your requests? Use console.log to find out what"data" is in your JS function, are you sure the value is set and properly formatted? the "data" object should be in JSON format, like `{"name":"some value",....}`

Comment: Print(request) results :<WSGIRequest: POST '/jobs/DeleteJobFile/'>
print(request.body) results : b'filename=name+-+Copy&csrfmiddlewaretoken=vJnRwQ3fwLSgFWyJJxi94yoG8acgx0vqHfrFbRHJBfOZmMDXq0vFLcLzVPofL35k'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I made it to work, from what hansTheFranz said, I tried the print request.body so first I stringified it to have a {"name":"SomeOne"} format and then in my view function I decoded it, here's my code:
This is the html:

```
function DeleteJobFile(name) {
            var obj = {'FileName':name};
            var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'DeleteJobFile/',

{#                data: name#}
                data:myJSON,
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    document.location.reload(true);
                    alert("The text has been changed." + name);
                }
            });
        }
```

This is the view:

```
def DeleteJobFile(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body = json.loads(body_unicode)
        name = body['FileName']    
        print(name)
    else:
        print('no')
    return render(request, 'JobApp/JobApp.html', {'FileList': FileList})
```

If there's any simpler way please inform me.
One more thing is to deal with the CSRF thing, I had to add a @csrf_exempt before my def func... at views.py, django won't accept when I add csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' to my data, how can I use it? 
Besides I still have the problem to call file_name.id, actually I want to have access to the n-th element from the myfile list, where n is also an input to html from view.py.